# Add and Remove Keyframe on time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 moving objects with my keyframe:

```
  @keyframes rotation {
        0% {
            transform: rotateY(0deg)
        }
        10% {
            transform: rotateY(55deg)
        }
        30% {
            transform: rotateY(55deg)
        }
        60% {
            transform: rotateY(230deg)
        }
        80% {
            transform: rotateY(230deg)
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotateY(360deg)
        }
    }
```

this moves my object ->

css:

```
.object{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 2s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(230deg);
}


.cb2 {
    animation: rotation 20s infinite linear;
}
```

Now I want the first object to spin once then when it's done the second one should spin, when the second one is done the third one should spin.

I tried something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#first").addClass('cb2');
}, 10000);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#first").removeClass('cb2');
}, 16500);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#second").addClass('cb2');
}, 16600);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#second").removeClass('cb2');
}, 29900);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#third").addClass('cb2');
}, 30100);
```

First of all, that doesn't really work, because it's not really smooth but the main problem is, that this will do the job once, but I want to loop this.
Is that possible ?

HTML:

```
  <div id="container">
        <div id="thrdcb" class="position-absolute displayres" style="top:100px;left: 10%;bottom:0;pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div data-index="7" data-chapter="1" data-names="opacity,margin-left" data-start-values="0,-10px" data-end-values="1,0" data-delay="1000" style="opacity: 0;" class="wontainer">
                            <div class="navbar"></div>
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-card">
                                    <div id="firstcube" class="object">
                                        <div class="face one">
                                            <p id="firstnewssub" style="position: relative; background-color: #a3ba1e; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face two">
                                            <p id="firstnewssub2" style="position: relative; background-color: #a3ba1e; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face three">
                                            <img src="data/img/testasdd.png" alt="" />
                                            <p id="aaaae" style="position: relative; background-color: #a3ba1e; padding: 10px;">
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face four">
                                            <img src="data/img/asddfff.png" alt="" />
                                            <p id="firstnews2" style="position: relative; background-color: #a3ba1e; padding: 10px;">
                                            </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a id="rrzuii" href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-index="7" data-chapter="1"
                                        data-names="opacity, pointer-events" data-start-values="0, none" data-end-values="1, all" data-delay="1000" style="opacity: 0; margin-left: 0px;text-align: center; cursor: pointer;display: none;" class="asdz7">

                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="scndcb" class="position-absolute displayres" style="top:100px;right: 10%;bottom:0;pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div data-index="7" data-chapter="1" data-names="opacity,margin-left" data-start-values="0,-10px" data-end-values="1,0" data-delay="1000" style="opacity: 0;" class="wontainer">
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-card">
                                    <div id="thirdcube" class="object">
                                        <div class="face one">
                                            <p id="lppzz" style="position: relative; background-color: #62798b; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face two">
                                            <p id="iottt" style="position: relative; background-color: #62798b; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face three">
                                            <img src="data/img/asdaqqqqq.png" alt="" />
                                            <p id="thirdnews1" style="position: relative; background-color: #62798b; padding: 10px;">
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face four">
                                            <img src="data/img/uthhase.png" alt="" />
                                            <p id="thirdnews2" style="position: relative; background-color: #62798b; padding: 10px;">
                                            </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a id="aaklptt" href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-index="7" data-chapter="1" data-names="opacity, pointer-events"
                                        data-start-values="0, none" data-end-values="1, all" data-delay="1000" style="opacity: 0; margin-left: 0px;text-align: center; cursor: pointer;display: none;" class="-blue">

                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cubepointer" class="position-absolute displayres" style="top: 100px; left: 20%; right: 20%; bottom: 0px;pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div data-index="7" data-chapter="1" data-names="opacity,margin-left" data-start-values="0,-10px" data-end-values="1,0" data-delay="1000" style="opacity: 0;" class="wontainer">
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-card">
                                    <div id="secondcube" class="object">
                                        <div class="face one">
                                            <p id="dghh" style="position: relative; background-color: #e07a0c; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face two">
                                            <p id="aas" style="position: relative; background-color: #e07a0c; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face three">
                                            <img src="data/img/adasd.png" alt="" />
                                            <p id="ffss" style="position: relative; background-color: #e07a0c; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="face four">
                                            <img src="data/img/testm.png" alt="" />
                                            <p id="zz" style="position: relative; background-color: #e07a0c; padding: 10px;">

                                            </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a id="rdda" href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-index="99" data-chapter="1" data-names="opacity, pointer-events" data-start-values="0, none" data-end-values="1, all"
                                        data-delay="9999" style="opacity: 0; margin-left: 0px;text-align: center; cursor: pointer;display: none;" class="font-weight font">

                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What I noticed trying similar things is that stuff like this unsyncs really quickly especially when tabbing out. I usually work with `animationend` `animationstart` events now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent/AnimationEvent

Comment: It sounds as though you ought to be able to do this in a continuous animation, though @pso comment is worth noting, but I am unclear exactly what your HTML structure is, could you include it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the animation event. In your case the animation is defined as `animation: rotation 20s infinite linear;`, so to stop the animation and start the next you need to look for the `animationiteration` event.

I wrapped the elements in a `<div>` for the event listener. At the same time this wrapper can be used for finding the next element to animate.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

//container.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
container.addEventListener('animationiteration', e => {
  $(e.target).removeClass('cb2');
  let next = e.target.parentElement.querySelector(`div#${e.target.id}~div.object`);
  if(next){
    $(next).addClass('cb2');
  }else{
    $(e.target.parentElement.querySelector(`div.object`)).addClass('cb2');
  }
});

// initiate animation
$(container.querySelector(`div.object`)).addClass('cb2');
```

```css
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.object {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(230deg);
}

.cb2 {
  animation: rotation 20s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="first" class="object">A</div>
  <div id="second" class="object">B</div>
  <div id="third" class="object">C</div>
</div>
```

#### Update

The first example assumes that all the `div.object` elements are siblings. The following example is showing how `div.object` elements can be in a nested structure. In this case there is a need for a variable `objects` that hold all the `div.object`s. The selection of the next element happens based on the index of the current element in the array.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

const objects = container.querySelectorAll('.object');

container.addEventListener('animationiteration', e => {
  $(e.target).removeClass('cb2');
  let currentIndex = [...objects].indexOf(e.target);
  let next = objects[currentIndex+1];
  if(next){
    $(next).addClass('cb2');
  }else{
    $(objects[0]).addClass('cb2');
  }
});

// initiate animation
$(objects[0]).addClass('cb2');
```

```css
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.object {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(230deg);
}

.cb2 {
  animation: rotation 20s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div id="first" class="object">A</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="second" class="object">B</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="third" class="object">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the next element by ID and not nextElementSibling ? Because I have other divs inbetween -> I updated the HTML inside.

Comment: @nanchalantflow I updated my answer. Instead of using `nextElementSibling` for finding the next element I use `querySelector()`.

Comment: Ok. But when I put the ID on top of the 3 Elements, the class cb2 won't go on the IDs firstcube, secondcube and thirdcube.

Comment: @chrwahl I have the same issue nanchalantflow mentioned with the elements in between

Comment: @nanchalantflow I made an update to my answer. Now, elements don't have to be on the same level. I think it fits your case better.

Comment: Could it be possible, that something in my HTML holds the Code back ? My first item gets the cb2 class perfectly fine but the other 2 don't...

Comment: I guess that you just reach '$(objects[0]).addClass('cb2');' because that will give your first 'object' your cb2 class. Your JS above won't execute correctly

Comment: Kinda.. Yes it will just add the cb2 Class to the first object, but if it wouldn't go trough the code above, my site wouldn't load properly, because it would stop loading the other JS which was already included from my side, because I load the example of chrwahl in my document ready function.

Comment: @nanchalantflow All the JS in my example should go into the document ready function. But I don't see why it should brake other things. See if you get any syntax errors. In any case try to `console.log(objects)` after the `const objects ...` line to see if the list only contains the first element or if there are more.

Comment: did you add 'infinite' to your cb2 class ? like @chrwahl put in his example ? you can also add 'animation-iteration-count: infinite'

Comment: I forgot the infinite in cb2 .. Now it worked thank you guys! ... sry

Answer (score 1):

While it is theoretically possible to do this in CSS, using one set of keyframes and the animation-delay CSS property, there is a possibility that timings could get out of step, as pointed out in a comment (depending for example how busy the system is with other things).

This snippet therefore sets the animation going for one cycle on the first object, listens for when that animation ends, removes the animation and puts it onto the next object and so on. That way it is guaranteed to keep in step sequentially, even if things get a little delayed sometime.

```js
const objects = document.querySelectorAll('.objects > *');
const num = objects.length;
let n = 0;
objects.forEach(object => {
  object.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    object.classList.remove('cb2');
    n = (n + 1) % num;
    objects[n].classList.add('cb2');
  });
});
objects[n].classList.add('cb2');
```

```css
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.objects>* {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(230deg);
}

.objects>*:nth-child(1) {
  background: cyan;
}

.objects>*:nth-child(2) {
  background: magenta;
}

.objects>*:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.cb2 {
  animation: rotation 20s 1 linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="objects">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```